# jquery .css не записывает стиль в тег. Если удалить 'transform':rotate, то работает 'transform':translate

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(window).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    var w = $(window).width();
    var h = $(window).height();
    var offsetX = 0.5 - e.pageX / w;
    var offsetY = 0.5 - e.pageY / h;

    $(".parallax").each(function(i,el){
        var offset = parseInt($(el).data('offset'));

        var translate = "translate3d(" + Math.round(offsetX * offset)
         + "px," + Math.round(offsetY * offset) + "px, 0px)";
         console.log(translate)

        var rotate = "rotate3d(" + Math.round(offsetX * offset)
         + "deg," + Math.round(offsetY * offset) + "deg, 0, 0)";
         console.log(rotate)


         $(el).css({
            'transform':translate,
            'transform':rotate
         })

    })
})
```

Comment: Потому что значения в `transform` должны указываться через пробел - `'transform':translate+' '+rotate`

Comment: @Cheg, ответы в ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, одинаковые ключи у объекта не бывают - побеждает последний:

```js
console.log({
  'transform': "translate(1px, 1px)",
  'transform': "rotate(90deg)"
}['transform'])
```

Во-вторых, в css только одно свойство `transform`, значения которого надо перечислять через пробел:

```
$(el).css('transform', translate + " " + rotate)
```

либо

```
$(el).css({
  transform: translate + " " + rotate
})
```